# WP7 SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am creating a small RSS Reader application.

The code I am using to get the xml is as follows:

```
    void PhonePage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.benchmark.pl/rss/aktualnosci-pliki.xml"));
    }

    void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result))
        {
            feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
            NewsFeed.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the SyndicationFeed item template does not fit the template in the xml file. I somehow need to edit the template so that the text is inserted correctly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `SyndicationFeed` you'll have to use the objects it defines. It would, however, be easy to convert this to something that more closely reflects your XML.

Assuming you had a class like:

```
class MyFeedItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Uri Link { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset PubDate { get; set; }
}
```

You could convert the SyndicationFeed items to it like:

```
private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SyndicationFeed feed;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(e.Result))
    {
        feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        NewsFeed.ItemsSource = ParseFeed(feed);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<MyFeedItem> ParseFeed(SyndicationFeed feed)
{
    return feed.Items.Select(item => new MyFeedItem
                                            {
                                                Title = item.Title.Text,
                                                Link = item.Links.First().Uri,
                                                Description = item.Summary.Text,
                                                PubDate = item.PublishDate
                                            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please put the whole code? when I tried to insert the loop in my wc_OpenReadCompleted function I get the error message that it can't be 'void'.